# Enabling vignette compression for R CMD build in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, devtools

I am using RStudio for package development in windows environment. I need to enable pdf vignette compression to avoid `'gs+qpdf' made some significant size reductions:` warning.

I have added `--compact-vignettes="gs+qpdf"` as additional options to **Project Options : Build Tools** > **Build Source Package**, but there is no change in the size of pdf vignette in the source package built using `devtools::build()`.

I have also added to the YAML header in the vignette latex compression options as follows.

```
header-includes:
- \pdfminorversion=5
- \pdfcompresslevel=9
- \pdfobjcompresslevel=2
```

Still there is no change.

However I am getting the desired compression while using `tools::compactPDF`
with `gs_cmd = Sys.getenv("R_GSCMD")` and `gs_quality = "ebook` arguments.

How to get the desired compression while building packages for avoiding the warning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found, for some reason (perhaps related to the quotes?), that RStudio doesn't like the `--compact-vignettes="gs+qpdf"`.

Instead, I used `--compact-vignettes=both`, which did the trick for me, when using RStudio's "Build" panel.

From the command line, you'd need to type `devtools::build(args = c('--compact-vignettes=both'))`. (For versions of devtools < 2.2.2, replace `args` with `build_args`.)

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486518-Customizing-Package-Build-Options has more details.

Comment: As of `devtools` version 2.4.5, the correct usage is `devtools::build(args = c('--compact-vignettes=both'))`. Notice that it is now args and no longer build_args.